# Apply a Moving average to different closing prices of currencies simultaneously

Tags: python, dataframe, moving-average

[image]I want to apply a single moving average to different closing prices at the same time on my Data Frame.

```
Open    Close   ... High    Low
AUDUSD=X    EURUSD=X    GBPUSD=X    NZDUSD=X    USDCAD=X    USDCHF=X    USDJPY=X    AUDUSD=X    EURUSD=X    GBPUSD=X    ... USDCAD=X    USDCHF=X    USDJPY=X    AUDUSD=X    EURUSD=X    GBPUSD=X    NZDUSD=X    USDCAD=X    USDCHF=X    USDJPY=X
Date                                                                                    
2019-01-02  0.704722    1.146132    1.275234    0.671362    1.36250 0.98180 109.660004  0.704791    1.146171    1.275429    ... 1.36596 0.98925 109.674004  0.698470    1.134572    1.258463    0.666298    1.35690 0.9794  108.730003
2019-01-03  0.692008    1.131734    1.251878    0.663398    1.36300 0.98916 107.449997  0.691898    1.131811    1.252191    ... 1.36440 0.98977 108.271004  0.691946    1.131734    1.251878    0.661559    1.34736 0.9845  106.776001
2019-01-04  0.700722    1.139095    1.262897    0.668852    1.34760 0.98726 107.865997  0.700624    1.139108    1.262881    ... 1.34906 0.99068 108.583000  0.699496    1.134816    1.261782    0.667361    1.33814 0.9852  107.513000
2019-01-07  0.712606    1.141292    1.273285    0.674450    1.33689 0.98577 108.488998  0.712378    1.141044    1.273496    ... 1.33760 0.98577 108.625000  0.711551    1.140524    1.272426    0.673179    1.32882 0.9789  108.036003
2019-01-08  0.714602    1.147934    1.278691    0.675548    1.32967 0.97929 108.642998  0.714592    1.147974    1.278609    ... 1.33190 0.98333 109.077003  0.711789    1.142465    1.271488    0.670979    1.32670 0.9788  108.449997
```

```
forex_data_1['Moving average'] = forex_data_1['Close'].rolling(window=30).mean()
```

ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column Moving average

Comment: Please format your question properly. It is compleately unreadable like this.

Answer (score 1):

Your attributes concering the df (rolling, mean) generally works.
The problem is your df itself, it seems that you don´t adress it correct.
I guess, forex_data_1['Close'] is no column. For deeper analysis, you must post your dataframe in a better readable way. As mentioned by @atteggiani, without this, analysis for your error is not possible.

This works fine for me:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,7],'B':[2,3,4,5,6]})

df['rollmean'] = df['A'].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

Result:

```
     A  B  rollmean
0  1.2  2       NaN
1  1.3  3      1.25
2  1.4  4      1.35
3  1.5  5      1.45
4  7.0  6      4.25
```

Solution with iteration over rows as asked:

```
for c in df.columns:
    df['rm'+c]=df[c].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

Solution after specific definition of df from questioner forex_data.head():

```
for c in forex_data.columns:
    forex_data['rm'+c[0]+c[1]]=forex_data[c[0]][c[1]].rolling(window=2).mean()
```

... fills separate columns at the end of the table with prefix rm and addresses each tuple of multicolumns. The columns in your dataframe are multicolumns. You adddressed in your example only one attribute of the column, not both. If you insert print(c) directly under the for-loop you understand what I mean.

Comment: yours is nice and simple. can you apply your rollmean to both 'A' and 'B' at the same time?

Comment: moved to my answer ...

Comment: I see your response and is helpful.